# ToC style, using ToCloft

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I'm preparing my thesis in LYX. Previously I asked a question about article class, but then I've found that it would be better to use report class instead. I use a tocloft package and  code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[LGR,T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=1.1cm,headheight=17pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{subscript}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand*\LyXZeroWidthSpace{\hspace{0pt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\ProvideTextCommand{\~}{LGR}[1]{\char126#1}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrtext}{%
  \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{T2A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\leavevmode{\cyrtext #1}}

\newcommand{\lyxmathsym}[1]{\ifmmode\begingroup\def\b@ld{bold}
  \text{\ifx\math@version\b@ld\bfseries\fi#1}\endgroup\else#1\fi}

\ProvideTextCommandDefault{\guillemotleft}{%
  {\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char'50\kern-.15em\char'50}%
\penalty10000\hskip0pt\relax%
}
\ProvideTextCommandDefault{\guillemotright}{%
  \penalty10000\hskip0pt%
  {\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char'51\kern-.15em\char'51}%
}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textquotedbl}{T1}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Введение}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum} {Глава }
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{5em}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0}

\makeatother

\usepackage[style=gost-numeric,bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{0C__Users_1_Documents_My_diss_All_bib.bib}
\begin{document}

\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\begin{center}
{\large{}Титульная}\vspace{28pt}
\par\end{center}

\noindent \begin{center}
Специальность 01.04.11 -- физика магнитных явлений
\par\end{center}    

\newpage{}  

\tableofcontents 
\clearpage

\newpage{}

\chapter*{{\large{}Введение }}

\section*{{\normalsize{}Цели диссертационной работы}}

\section*{{\normalsize{}Апробация работы} }
  Основные результаты диссертационной..

\newpage{}

\chapter{{\large{}Литературный обзор}}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Природа обменного взаимодействия}}

\section{{\normalsize{}Обменные взаимодействия в соединениях РЗМ с Fe, Ni,
Mn}}

\section{{\normalsize{}Кристаллическая структура...}}

\newpage{}

\chapter{{\large{}Технология приготовления и аттестация образцов }}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Микроструктура }}

\section{{\normalsize{}Методика измерения магнитокалорического эффекта в малых
полях и больших полях}}

\section{{\normalsize{}Измерение магнитной восприимчивости}}

\newpage{}

\chapter{{\large{}Результаты}}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Гигантская объёмная ...  }}

\vspace{42pt}

\section{{\normalsize{}Магнитные свойства...}}

\vspace{42pt}

\newpage{}

\chapter{{\large{}Выводы}}

\newpage{}

\chapter*{{\large{}Литература}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Литература}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

There are 2 points still looking not like they should.
First one- the header of ToC is not centered. However I used a command \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont} that should provide centering.

And I need the chapter ('Глава ') name to be followed by dots just like section name.

How can I edit these?

Comment: For a thesis, instead of report you should consider use book, scrbook,  memoir or tufte-book or one templte of https://ctan.org/topic/dissertation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [minimal working examples (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to simplify troubleshooting.

Firstly, you're on the right track with centering the TOC title. Adding this command to the preamble should produce the desired output.

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
```

Secondly, you can get generate leading dots after section entries in the table of contents by adding the following command to your preamble.

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
```

Putting it all together into a MWE.

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}

% centre toc title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

% add leading dots to chapters in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{Some Section}

\chapter{Second}
\section{Another Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]